# Connection made during the creation of Dataframe and select (or like operation or method) on created Dataframe in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, database-connection, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for solution of below question.

- Question : When we create Dataframe in Apache Spark, with a table from database, it's obvious that the connection will be made. but what if i perform some operation (like select()), will it attempt to reconnect ?
- or all the operation will be remembered, and just one time the request makes connection **in a Lazy-Loading way ?**

*Basically, i am concern about making minimal call(request) to my database.

Because i heard that it can be efficient, and specially when you are dealing with big data. In my case, I possibly work on the creating Dataframe and performing operation on it, and data for that can be Big data. So, it will be wise if i just fetch the data once from the database.

it will be nice if anyone can help with the knowledge that what goes on behind the scene.

suggestion for any literature,links is also appreciated.

Thank you in advance..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is generic and depending upon the Driver, the results and behavior can be different.

for example - Assuming that you are using Type-4 JDBC driver and adding Driver jar files in `SPARK_CLASSPATH` and your Driver supports connection pooling, then once the connection is created it will be reused for subsequent request but in case your driver does not then each time you make a NEW request it will create different connection. This was the case with RDBMS and as on Spark-1.6 supports following RDBMS: -

1. MySQL
2. Postgres
3. DB2
4. MySqlServer
5. Oracle
6. Derby

Now coming to you question, Once you load the data from database and DataFrame is created then your data is now already there in the Spark/ Cluster Memory and all subsequent Query, executed over the same DataFrame is executed over the data which is already in the memory. Spark does not connect to any underlying database. But in case you create a new DataFrame, then there would be calls to the underlying database.
Also it is important to remember all these transformation happens only when we invoke any output operation on a DataFrame like `print` or `registerTempTable` or `saveAs...` etc.

Comment: Thanks @Sumit.. I can understand now. And ya i was not certain whether to mention db name or not so i didn't. By the way it's Cassandra. And i have another little doubt. It does actually mean that Dataframe fetches all the data from table first and then perform the operations..?? Sorry.. haven't enough repo to upvote your answer.

Comment: No. Actually it depends upon your SQL Query or Operation used to Load the data from underlying database. You may choose to load the partial data and not the whole data by using some filtering. In case of Cassandra you can perform server side filtering too. see [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md)

Comment: I have looked at your suggested link.. thanks for it.. But i would like to say something. I agree that we can fetch only required data by applying filter on it. But it can be done when we work with RDD. but i think it couldn't while working with Dataframe. In my case, with cassandra, i can only fire the queries which are supported by CQL through RDD. While i can fire SQL queries when i use Dataframe.